# I have created volumes with Docker Desktop, I see the volumes using "docker volume ls" but the folder in windows are empy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-desktop

I have got a docker compose file that uses a volume, then I check that the volume is created while my container is running.

[image]

Then I go to the folder where the volumes are stored in docker desktop, but the folder is empty.

[image]

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  backnode:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    image: foo-backnode:1.0.0
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    volumes: 
      - html:/var/log/foo
    networks:
      - internal
    ports: 
      - "3001:3001"

networks:
  internal:
    internal: false

volumes: 
  html:
    external: false
```

I expect to see the log files produced by my application.

**Edit:**

All this works properly under linux enviroment (ubuntu).

[image]

Comment: You can't directly access the contents of named volumes.  Bind-mount a host directory, or set up your application to log to stdout and review the `docker logs`.

Comment: Yes I do, in linux the directory is /var/lib/docker/volumes/[volume_name]/, i can see the files (check the main post, i have edited with a screenshot)